# Is there any way to leave Skuldafn without a re-load?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So, I'm starting to feel like I made the trip to Skuldafn woefully unprepared.  I've managed to take down a fair number of the mobs that awaited me here, but I'm out of health pots and pushing the limits of my carry cap.  Is there any way I can go home to sell my loot and re-stock, without having to re-load the game?

I've tried re-calling the guy that got me here, but he's not coming.  Fast Travel seems to be disabled.

Comment: I had the same trouble, the dragons were easy but the mobs were much tougher than expected. I ended up just putting the difficulty down a level, was ok after that.

Comment: As for carrying capacity, it's likely the junk you have is just that: junk. Find some stuff that's purely vendor trash and just drop it in a pile. Money shouldn't be an issue that far into the game, and it's easy enough to make more to compensate the losses later.

Comment: @Andy_Vulhop Actually, I don't think I was really "that late in the game".  If I can't even handle the Skuldafn battles without running out of pots, that means I'm seriously under-equipped both in items and stats.  By the way, my carry cap was only 300.  Since I was playing primarily as a mage, Stamina was my dump stat.  The entire Skuldafn/Sovengarde quest area is probably equivalent to at least two or three regular dungeons.

Comment: @Iszi I disagree. You ran out of pots because it's a hard zone. The dragons are pushovers, but every draugr I fought was rather beefy. Additionally, it's about as long as 1 of the longer dungeons. The entirety of your time in Sovengarde is actually quite short, relatively speaking. Trust me, you won't miss the gold from some draugr weapons. You can blow through one dungeon and replace it all plus more, and you can basically print money with crafting in this game.

Comment: same as me. i had saved over alot of time. lvl 34 with a mix of blades and ebony stuff as a 2 and one handed warrior. Dragons were really easy but after i died about 20 times in the temple section with no soul gems, potions because of vampirisim's non-regenerating stats, that it was impossible. i then realised that i had the difficulty lvl on expert..

Comment: Enchanting a few iron daggers with Daedra banishing using nothing but a petty soul gem will break almost any vendor's bank.

Comment: Related: [Can I get back to Skyrim from Sovngarde?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/157166/4797)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there's no way to leave Skuldafn until the quest is over.

Fast Travel is disabled from that location.  Also, if you look at the map, you're really not anywhere *on* the map.  Moving the map around, your location will seem to shift almost as if the marker is actually at a different height than the land where it seems to be located.

> Additionally, you can not recall Odahviing to carry you home.  You may use the shout, but he will not come.

So, it seems the only way to get out of Skuldafn if you can't handle the heat is to re-load from a point before you went to Skuldafn.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to 'Fast Travel' out, I simply walked down the hill into the river, and it then let me 'Fast Travel'. I couldn't get back sadly, so I had to make a new save.
It is possible to get out of the location, but once you do, you can't go back in, you should just go to 'Novice' difficulty, It is the easiest one, and you start off the game with a Healing spell, why not use that, as everyone has magicka.

Alduin is easier than a Draugr Overlord, in my opinion. I fought him with plain steel armour, on Novice difficulty, it was just like fighting an Elder Dragon with Daedric Armour/Weapons. Even if it is still too hard, you have two options from there...

1) Make a new save, and get better, and more stuff before going there.

2) Keep trying until you succeed. You may die a lot, but you'll get there.

In my game, I have been only on Novice, and haven't died from any enemies, and I am a level 37. All my deaths are from falling.
As I was typing that above 'Death Sentence', I thought of another option...

3) Be better at gaming.

As I thought that 'Death Sentence' part was quite funny, I have chosen to give you one more option.

4) Rush it. If you rush it, you can still get past and go to [SPOILERS] Sovngarde.

I suggest not rushing it, as there is a Dragon Priest at the portal to Sovngarde.
He has a mask, this mask is unobtainable in any other way. So, if you want to get the Secret One, which can be found at Labyrinthian, in a circle room, which has a wooden mask, you put it on, and you go back in time, to where you may place the Masks to get the Secret One.

As this game has many things to do, which requires many things only obtainable ONCE. This game can get really irritating. So, have fun on your travels. Alduin's death looks very epic. You should totally try your best to get to him, just to see his death.

-Anonymous

Comment: Don't think Fast Traveling out is possible anymore.  I managed to make it through the mountains into the Riften area and still couldn't Fast Travel.

Answer (score -7):

Am not sure what you mean about reload the game.

When you leave a dungeon, the mobs you have killed should mostly be still dead. I say mostly because if I return to a 'cleared' dungeon I always seem to bump into something living.

In theory you should be able to walk out of the place partly cleared, then fast travel to where-ever, restock on potions and sell stuff etc, then fast travel back.
All the mobs you have killed should still be dead, and you carry on where you left off.

Have you walked out of Skuldafin BEFORE trying to fast travel home ?
Are there any enemies near you - IF you are outside ? Do you see any message when you try to fast travel ?

Comment: I don't think you can "Walk out of Skuldafin" because it is a place that you can only visit with the aid of a dragon.

Comment: @Resorath Ahh yes. So many place names I didnt remember this one as being the dragon one.

Comment: Skuldafin isn't part of the map.