# Can I get back to Skyrim from Sovngarde?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm at Sovngarde, I've used all my healing potions and I can not defeat the guy who's gaurding the bridge. Is there anyway to go back to skyrim and buy potions? Is there any other way I can get potions? Or, Can I summon a dragon in Sovngarde?

I'm level 25 magicka is 140 health is 200 but +30 since I'm hearing a necklace of health and 200 stamina if it helps

Comment: Doesn't quick travel work? Also, tone down the panic while asking, it helps the reading.

Comment: Related: [Is there any way to leave Skuldafn without a re-load?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/46153/4797)

Comment: You want to  slay alduin at 200 health ? Do you believe everything greybeards tell you?

Comment: I hope you got this sorted - I found that retreating from the bridge and a few well placed arrows did the trick. I was a higher level (and therefore better kit than level 25 would have). If I recall correctly you don't have to defeat him - just hurt him badly enough to prove you are a warrior.

Answer (score 6):

When in Skuldafn:

> The portal to Sovngarde is the only exit from Skuldafn and fast travel is not possible.  [[source]](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Skuldafn)

So even if you could exit Sovngarde back, you would not be able to reach skyrim.

Your best option at this point is probably to load an older saved game, before going to Skuldafn.